# TaskscheduleR job returns fetch.write_memory error but works as a local job in RStudio on a virtual machine

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chron, r-taskscheduler

I'm trying to set up an automated job that builds an csv file (by pulling aggregates from multiple MySQL databases) and sends an email out on a daily schedule. The entire script works as a local job (via RStudio jobs v1.2.1335) if the script is run through RStudio normally. However, when the job is automated through `taskscheduleR` addin, it returns the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Could not resolve host: .domo.com
Calls: <Anonymous> ... request_fetch -> request_fetch.write_memory -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

My guess is that my DomoR package is masking the `fetch` function multiple times:

```
Welcome to DomoR

Attaching package: 'DomoR'

The following object is masked from 'package:RMySQL':

    fetch

The following object is masked from 'package:DBI':

    fetch
```

But I'm not entirely sure if that is the issue. I am running this through an aws EC2 instance running Microsoft Server 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my username and password was not being used in the automated job. It seems that your `.Renviron` file will not be pulled properly in a EC2 automated job.

You can solve this problem by getting your `.Renviron` and loading it in as a dataframe.  Then calling in the credentials.